# Map Complex Json to Pojo Class

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

I am sending the following request (using Spring Boot)

```
 ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, request, String.class);
```

response is  the json object(i have ommitted lot of fields in json object)

```
{
    "customer": {
        "id": 100,
        "ci": {
            "lDb": "11",
            "localId": "1"
        },
        "cusdata": {},
        "rating": {
            "id": 3140,
            "dateTime": "2019-09-21 06:45:41.10",
            "rawData": {
                "seg": "XYZ",
                "seg2": "XYZ",
                "et": "XYZ_CORP",
                "CountryCodes": [
                    "IN"
                ],
                "doBusiness": "2017-09-20"
                ],
                ...

                ....
                ...
                ...



    "status": "SUCCESS"
}
```

I need to map the below fields to a Pojo Class

1.localId
 2.seg
 3.seg2
 4.status

How can i create the PojoClass such that those fields are mapped automatically

So basically how will my PojoClass should look like?

```
ResponseEntity<PojoClass> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, request, PojoClass.class);
```

Comment: Try this: https://github.com/joelittlejohn/jsonschema2pojo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your PojoClass has to follow the structure of the JSON that your are receiving and have the fields that your are interested (or all of them).

For the first level class:

```
public class PojoClass {
    private Customer customer;
    private String status;
    ...
}
```

Then, create a Customer class for the customer fields and create more classes for the rest of the fields:

```
public class Customer {
    public String id;
    public CI ci;
    public CustData custData;
    ...
}
```

Comment: is there anyway i can get value of seg field from json?

Comment: Yes, from my example, continue creating the class hierarchy until you create RawData class with seg, seg2, et, ... fields

Comment: Thnaks.It works  perfectly fine. But i ended up creating 3-4 classes.Cani avoid it anyway?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that you use sites like http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/. There, you can select many options on the right panel and adjust POJO you want to get from JSON schema.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom class PojoClass

```
  public class PojoClass {
        private Integer id;
        private Object ci;
        private Object cusdata;
        private Object rating;
        private Object status;
    }

ResponseEntity<PojoClass> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(url,HttpMethod.GET,request,new ParameterizedTypeReference<PojoClass>(){
        });
```